# Nesting JSPs inside custom JSP Tag scope

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I have created a handy tag library for my JSP page.  It looks like this:

```
<myTag:getContent>

    <div id="metadata">
        <myTag:printContent arg="meta"/>
    </div>
    <div id="data">
        <myTag:printContent arg="data"/>
    </div>

</myTag>
```

getContent contains a RESTful web service that initializes and sets a few variables so that when I use the printContent with their respective arguments, it just has to print the variables as opposed to re-fetch the content.

The problem is that in the practical application, the calls to print contents lie deep inside different page snips:

```
<myTag:getContent>

    <jsp:include page=".../.../.../this.jsp"/> 

    <jsp:include page=".../.../.../that.jsp"/> 

</myTag>
```

I have the myTag library defined at the top of each page, but I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in the internal JSPs at the "myTag:printContent"

What do I do?  Is this even possible considering the real internal jsp pages have other tag libraries and logic?

The getContent is the following attribute inside the .tld (tag library descriptor)

```
<body-content>JSP</body-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like the good old step back and look problem is real here.  I switched the jsp:includes to   directive includes.  For those who are unfamiliar:

```
<myTag:getContent>
    <%@include file=".../.../.../this.jsp"%> 
    <@%include file=".../.../.../that.jsp"%> 
</myTag>
```

This works because now the scope is relevant as the include here is static at translation time vs jsp:include which is dynamic at request time.